# Get UIImageView CGPoints

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uicolor, cgpoint

i want to get all the points in my UIImageVeiw , so i can change "some" points colors without the need of UITouch .. is it possible?

What i am thinking about is:

1. get all points in uiimageview
2. get color of each point.
3. if the previous color= some specific color, then change the color.

i googled this a lot but i found that all the tutorials depends on UITouch like this http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/

my main goal now is how to get all points ?!

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution .. hope it will help anyone one day.
this method returns array of pixels in some image.

```
-(NSArray*)getRGBAsFromImage:(UIImage*)image atX:(int)x andY:(int)y count:(int)count
{
   NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];

// First get the image into your data buffer
CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                             bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
CGContextRelease(context);

// Now your rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format.
NSUInteger byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * y) + x * bytesPerPixel;
for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i)
{
    CGFloat red   = (rawData[byteIndex]     * 1.0) / 255.0;
    CGFloat green = (rawData[byteIndex + 1] * 1.0) / 255.0;
    CGFloat blue  = (rawData[byteIndex + 2] * 1.0) / 255.0;
    CGFloat alpha = (rawData[byteIndex + 3] * 1.0) / 255.0;
    byteIndex += bytesPerPixel;

    UIColor *acolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
    [result addObject:acolor];
}

free(rawData);

return result;}
```

you can call it like this:

```
NSArray*arrayOfPixels= [self getRGBAsFromImage:_patternFirstImage.image atX:_patternFirstImage.frame.origin.x andY:_patternFirstImage.frame.origin.y count:_patternFirstImage.frame.size.width*_patternFirstImage.frame.size.height];
NSLog(@"arrayOfPixels = %zd",[arrayOfPixels count]);
```

you can loop through all pixels to get its color like the following :

```
for(int i=0;i<[arrayOfPixels count];i++){
    NSLog(@"objects = ---%@----",[arrayOfPixels objectAtIndex:i]);
    if([self color:[arrayOfPixels objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xE0E0E0) withTolerance:0.2]){
        NSLog(@"index = %zd",i);
    }
}
```

thanx a lot for the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262893/2168496